# Add New Gist using the Github API

Tags: javascript, api, air, github

I'm making a small app in Adobe Air which I need to interact with the Github Gist API. However I'm kind of stuck.

If you're not familiar with Adobe Air you can still help, the `XMLHttpRequest` javascript object can do cross domain requests, as there is no domain as such. So theres nothing Adobe Air specific here.

Where I'm stuck is I think I need to authenticate myself then make the POST. I just don't understand it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your script is that though you're sending a POST method, you're adding the data in the URL as though it were a GET. You just need to change `xmlhttp.send(NULL)` to `xmlhttp.send(data)`, where `data` is the query data you were appending to the `gists` URL before (including the file and authentication information).

As a simple example, here's an excerpt from [a bash script](https://gist.github.com/8d1837445cb1375d9b1c) creating a new gist:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -z "$(git config github.token)" ]
then echo "warning: no api key found, to add follow instructions on github account page."
else echo "attempting to create a new gist using your github authentication..."; fi

SHA=$((curl https://gist.github.com/gists --include \
       --data login=$(git config github.user) \
       --data token=$(git config github.token) \
       --data action_button=private \
       --data 'file_ext[gistfile1]=txt' \
       --data 'file_contents[gistfile1]=Hello World, this is an example gist!' \
| perl -e 'for(<>){if(/^Location: https?:\/\/gist.github.com\/([0-9a-f]+)/){print $1}}')2>/dev/null)

echo "New example gist created at https://gist.github.com/$SHA"
```

Comment: I don't understand what format the POST data has to be in. Could you explain a little further please.

Comment: In your original script you had the line: "var url = gists+'?...'". Your post data would be everything I replaced with "...".

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to authenticate the user.

The XMLHttpRequest will just have to have the user name and the users API token included in the request.

Looking at the example ruby script provided by [github here](http://github.com/defunkt/gist/blob/master/gist.rb), you just have to provide the following attributes:

- File Extenstion
- file name
- content
- If the gist is private or not
- User login
- User API Token

[python](http://github.com/mattikus/pygist/blob/master/pygist.py) and [perl](http://github.com/miyagawa/gistp/blob/master/gistp) versions of the script

Comment: I think your file type/name and content have to be prefixed like the example.   'file_ext[gistfile1]' 'file_name[gistfile1]' 'file_contents[gistfile1]'